# AS3 movieclip trigger another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I just want to clarify, can a movieclip that triggers by interaction trigger another movieclip?

I am doing a function which using blowing function which is working by the way.

```
    function doEveryFrame(e:Event)
    {
            trace(mic.activityLevel);
            if(mic.activityLevel == 100)
            {
                ballMC.gotoAndPlay(1);
            }
    }
```

After above interaction ballMC reaches my rectangle graphic. From the rectangle, I want my blueballMC to just play.

I hope this is clear enough, though.

Comment: If the instance where this code is executing has a reference to `ballMc`, then yes. Otherwise no. Ie: if you manually add `ballMC` to `MC1` on the stage, MC1 could call `ballMC.gotoAndPlay(1)`.

Comment: Do you have example of the code? cause I'm very new to this and I look up for many tutorial but can't seems to find a proper...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is more than possible by:

1:  First check if the movieclip is on the frame you want it to be on (if you want it to be on the last frame, you can check the movieclip's `totalFrames` keyword):  `if(yourMovieClip.currentFrame == frameYouWantItToBeOnToTrigger)`

2: Trigger the next movieclip: `if(yourMovieClip.currentFrame == frameYouWantItToBeOnToTrigger)
{
nextMovieClip.gotoAndPlay(frameNumberForNextMovieClipToStartOn);
}`

And that's all there is to it.

Comment: do you mean by 

`if(mic.activityLevel == 100)
            {
                ballMC.gotoAndPlay(1);

}
    blueballMC.gotoAndPlay(2); }`

Something like that? Sorry if I dunno ^^"

but I manage but an error appear `5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: HELLOworld, doEveryFrame`

Comment: Your error is unrelated to your problem. Is this code on a frame? Need more info to help. Also there is most likely a typo in your `HELLOworld.as`.

Comment: @LiLee currentFrame is the movieclip's current frame.  It is likely your class has incorrect form of code.

Comment: @MartonPallagi is in the class document

@Doorhandle if put in like above question, the files have no problem at all. Just to recap back that is a interaction using sound to trigger my `ballMC` after `ballMC` hit my rectangle, my `blueballMC` will get trigger by 'ballMC'.

Comment: Thank you to both of you helped me along but I figure it out already :)